# awk command for string replacement and printing matched and unmatched strings

Tags: awk

I want to replace multiple strings (more than thousand) in  `File-1` with matching string from `File-2`

`File-1`:

```
Geneid Length s1 s2
1_1 6571 7 8
1_2 5041 3 0
1_3 1032 7 3    
1_4 1212 3 5    
1_5 1071 3 5    
2_1 7171 2 7
2_2 1038 1 1
2_3 9361 0 6
2_4 1056 5 1
```

`File-2` (map):

```
1_1
1_2 k0002
1_3
1_4
1_5 k0006   
2_1
2_2
2_3
2_4 k0528
```

Expected output:

```
Geneid Length s1 s2
1_1 6571 7 8
k0002 5041 3 0
1_3 1032 7 3    
1_4 1212 3 5    
k0006 1071 3 5  
2_1 7171 2 7
2_2 1038 1 1
2_3 9361 0 6
k0528 1056 5 1
```

I used the following `awk` command:

```
awk '
NR==FNR {                      
a[$1]=$2                    
next                       
}
{                               
print (($1 in a)?a[$1]:$1, $2, $3, $4)  
}' File-2 File-1 > File-3
```

which gives me this:

```
Geneid  Length  s1  s2
 6571 7 8
k0002 5041 3 0
 1032 7 3   
 1212 3 5   
k0006 1071 3 5  
 7171 2 7
 1038 1 1
 9361 0 6
k0528 1056 5 1
```

How to modify this `awk` command to keep unmatched strings?
Sorry, I am a newbie to linux and `awk` (trying to learn).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `($1 in a)?a[$1]:$1` prints either `a[$1]` or `$1` depending on whether `$1` is a key in `a`.  But all your keys are in `a`, so for example, for the key `1_1`, it prints the empty string which is the value of `a["1_1"]`.  The solution is to only populate `a` when there is a value to add for the key in `$1`.

```sh
awk 'NR==FNR { if (NF > 1) a[$1]=$2; next }
{ print (($1 in a)?a[$1]:$1, $2, $3, $4) }' File-2 File-1
```

For debugging a script like yours, it helps to add `print` statements at various points to see what the script is doing. Here's what I ended up doing to figure out what was wrong with your script.

```sh
# STILL BUGGY, DEBUGGING RUN
awk 'NR==FNR { print("a[" $1 "]=" $2); a[$1]=$2; next; }
{ print ($1 in a ? a[$1] : $1), $2, $3, $4, ($1 in a), a[$1], $1, ($1 in a ? "yes" : "no"), "end" }' File-2 File-1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '
    NR==FNR { if (NF>1) a[$1]=$2; next }
    $1 in a { $1=a[$1] }
1' file2 file1
Geneid Length s1 s2
1_1 6571 7 8
k0002 5041 3 0
1_3 1032 7 3
1_4 1212 3 5
k0006 1071 3 5
2_1 7171 2 7
2_2 1038 1 1
2_3 9361 0 6
k0528 1056 5 1
```

1. `if (NF>1)` efficiently ensures you only populate `a[]` with values from `file2` that you need, i.e. those that have a 2nd field,
2. `$1 in a` ensures you only change `$1` from `file` when an
   associated entry existed in `file2`. Do not test `a[$1]==""` or
   anything similar instead as that will populate `a[]` for every `$1`
   in file1 and so use up memory and increase execution time.
3. `1` at the end causes the current, possibly just-modified, line from `file1` to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Given that `File-2` won't be empty:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}a[$1]!=""{$1=a[$1]}1' File-2 File-1
Geneid Length s1 s2
1_1 6571 7 8
k0002 5041 3 0
1_3 1032 7 3
1_4 1212 3 5
k0006 1071 3 5
2_1 7171 2 7
2_2 1038 1 1
2_3 9361 0 6
k0528 1056 5 1
```

If it can be empty, and with `GNU awk`, you can replace `NR==FNR` with `ARGIND==1` or `FILENAME=="File-2"`.

Comment: Not testing for how many field exist in the `NR==FNR` block before populating `a[$1]=$2` means that there will be an entry in `a[]` for every line in File-2 instead of just the entries that need to exist so will use a lot more memory than necessary and potentially slow down the hash lookups. Doing `a[$1]!=""` instead of `$1 in a` in the subsequent block will then also add an entry to `a[]` for every line in File-1 using up more memory and slowing it down further if the $1s aren't identical between the 2 files.

Comment: @EdMorton  I was mainly thinking about conciseness when I wrote like that, yeah, good point, thanks :)